# java method can't run in a jsp file

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I have a problem.
I have configured in eclipse hibernate with a database in mysql.
I have created a file java, and if I try to save some data to database works perfectly.

The problem is, if I create a jsp file, and try to call the same method it doesn't work, I guess it doesn't connect with hibernate.

```
public class CreateData {
    public int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            SessionFactory sessFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setEmpName("Deepak Kumar");
            emp.setEmpMobileNos("000000");
            emp.setEmpAddress("Delhi - India");
            session.save(emp);
            tr.commit();
            System.out.println("Successfully inserted");
            sessFact.close();
    }




    public void insert() throws Exception {

            SessionFactory sessFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setEmpName("Deepak Kumar");
            emp.setEmpMobileNos("000000");
            emp.setEmpAddress("Delhi - India");
            session.save(emp);
            tr.commit();
            System.out.println("Successfully inserted");
            sessFact.close();
    }
           public int getAge(){return this.age;}
```

}

So, if a run the main of this class java ,everything works fine.

but I can't run insert() method in this jsp file (obviously does the some thing as the main )
JSP FILE example:
   jsp:useBean id= "user" class= "javabean.CreateData"  scope="session"

<% user.getAge();%>              // THIS WORKS

<% user.insert();%>   // THIS DOESN'T WORK

---

when I run the jsp gives me an error

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.savesclient_jsp._jspService(savesclient_jsp.java:121)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    javabean.insertClient.inserisci2(insertClient.java:61)
    org.apache.jsp.savesclient_jsp._jspService(savesclient_jsp.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    javabean.insertClient.inserisci2(insertClient.java:61)
    org.apache.jsp.savesclient_jsp._jspService(savesclient_jsp.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: What does `THIS DOESN'T WORK` mean?

Comment: in jsp the method getAge() works fine, the method insert() doesn't work

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ mean? What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: I have a table employee in mysql. If I run the class CreateData, the main populate the table. Now I want to populate the table in a jsp file. So I create a jsp file, when I run it, the method insert() doesn't work, I will show you the log file :

Comment: There's much more to the error than that. Post the full stack trace. Also, don't use scriptlets.

Comment: sorry, I am new to this forum.

Comment: Ok, so now we see `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`. Look that up.

Comment: yes, I saw but I don't understand what is the problem. It seems like it can't create an hibernate session

Comment: Look up `NoClassDefFoundError` and `ClassNotFoundException`. Your classpath is not correctly set.

Comment: how is not set correctly ? then why if I run only the java file it works fine ? what should I do ? thank you very much

Comment: This has been answered before. Just look up what a `ClassNotFoundException` is. This is a classpath issue. Find out how to properly set a classpath in a servlet web application.

Comment: ok thank you, I will look for answers

Comment: Glad to hear it. Careful, classpath conventions for web applications are different than standalone apps.